# How can I completely clear a bitmap from memory on Android?

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap, recycle

I just have a bitmap that I use to assign to a static variable. I did not set this to any imageview. After assigning it to a static variable, I want to delete it from memory by typing bitmap.recycle (). I don't get an error when I just use the bitmap.recycle () line, but when I try to switch to a different page, I get an error.

This code has no errors:

```
StaticVeriables.getScannedFromGallery=bitmap;
bitmap.recycle();
//Intent gallery1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditImage.class);
//gallery1.putExtra("isGallery",true);
//startActivity(gallery1);
//finish();
```

There is an error in this code:

```
StaticVeriables.getScannedFromGallery=bitmap;
bitmap.recycle();
Intent gallery1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditImage.class);
gallery1.putExtra("isGallery",true);
startActivity(gallery1);
finish();
```

Comment: Pls add Code in code format not as Image . And why are you using static `Bitmap` is it on purpose?

Comment: You can format code blocks using three backticks (`) or tildes (~) on the lines before and after your code. More formatting help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @peacetype like that?

Comment: @ADM I'm using static Bitmap because i can not send bitmap to other class with put extra, and thought I could use static variable to access from other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. It wasn't about switching to another activity. Since I assigned the bitmap to my static variable in the previous line, when I wrote bitmap.recycle (), I got an error because this bitmap is a reference static variable and I used this static variable in other classes. I solved this problem by copying my bitmap variable to my static variable. In that:

```
//I solved my problem with this line
StaticVeriables.getScannedFromGallery=bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(),true);
/*Whe should not do this
StaticVeriables.getScannedFromGallery=bitmap;*/
bitmap.recycle();
Intent gallery1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditImage.class);
gallery1.putExtra("isGallery",true);
startActivity(gallery1);
finish();
```